# How do I use a fetch get response more than once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch

I want to set both of these values in the state to be used later as variables.

```js
  const [dollarGoal, setDollarGoal] = React.useState(0); 
  const [dollarValue, setDollarValue] = React.useState(0);
  //fetching donation value
  fetch('api', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(r => setDollarValue(r.dollarValue))
    .then(r => setDollarGoal(r.dollarGoal));
```

But it gives the error:

```
Property 'dollarGoal' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  fetch('api', {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((r) => {
      setDollarValue(r.dollarValue)
      setDollarGoal(r.dollarGoal)
    });
```

The last two `.then` statements need to be combined. By calling `.then` twice, you're sending the result of `setDollarValue()` (a void function) to the next `.then`, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First off i think you should place your api call inside of a useEffect hook, because if not the fetch will be triggered again right after you set the values of your response with your useState hook, it might lead to an infinite call when it will be working.
Then, i think your response might not contain the property named 'dollarValue'.
Have you tried console.log your response ?